# Assign VB6 Variant into an Object

Tags: c#, vb6, object, variant

I have a VB6 application that uses a C# compiled Dll. I have been successfull in making this work by means of COM.
But my problem is that I have a Variant array with String and Double data types inside it. I need to pass this array to my C# Dll, which is receiving the array as an Object.
So, all I need to do is to convert the Variant array into an Object array "understandable" by C#. Anyone has any clue on it?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList(YourObjectArrayHere);
```

Answer (score 2):

This has to be done right from C# side of things; if it's not, then there isn't much you can do from VB6. That said, by default, a method declared like this:

```
void Foo(object[] a);
```

will be seen from VB6 as taking an array of `Variant` (or, on IDL level, as `SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)`).

If it doesn't work that way for you, then there's something wrong with your C# declarations - please post them so they may be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

object[] System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetObjectsForNativeVariants(IntPtr aSrcNativeVariant, int cVars)

Have you tried this method?

```
object[] result;
unsafe
{
  pin_ptr<object> pinObj = &obj;
  result = Marshal.GetObjectsForNativeVariants(new IntPtr(pinObj), objSize);
}
```

Haven't tried it myself but seems like it would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is the C# function declaration:

```
public double[][] CalcMatching( object[][] data1, object[][] data2, long dataLen1, long dataLen2, string matchingType )
```

This is the VB6 call:

```
result = matchingCalcObj.CalcMatching(data1, data2, dataLen1, dataLen2, Matching)
```

where `data1` and `data2` are arrays of Variant.

I don't think I can do much at the C#, like you guys are saying, once the error I get at the function calling is "Invalid procedure call or argument". Any option at the VB6 side?

Thanks for all the replies.